# form validation ajax submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

i have a form. i setting form validation input required

```
<input type="text" name="telefon" required="" placeholder="Telefon numaranız" class="form-control">
```

but when i click submit form empty or not empty sending. this is my javascript code

```
<script>
function uyem() {
      jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'src/ajax/kayit.php',

      data: $('#uyelik-formu').serialize(),
      error:function(){ $('#sonuc').html("Bir hata algılandı."); },
      success : function (sonuc){
        if(sonuc == 'msms'){
          $("#mod-sms").modal('show');
        }
        if (sonuc == 'hatak'){
          $("#sonuc").html('<div role="alert" class="alert alert-danger alert-icon alert-icon-colored alert-dismissible"><div class="icon"><span class="mdi mdi-close-circle-o"></span></div><div class="message"><button type="button" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" class="close"><span aria-hidden="true" class="mdi mdi-close"></span></button><strong>Hata!</strong> E-posta yada telefon başka bir üye tarafından kullanılmakta.</div></div>');
        }
        if(sonuc == 'error'){
          $("#mod-error").modal('show');
          setTimeout(function() { location.reload() },4000);
        }
        if (sonuc == 'hata'){
          $("#sonuc").html('<div role="alert" class="alert alert-danger alert-icon alert-icon-colored alert-dismissible"><div class="icon"><span class="mdi mdi-close-circle-o"></span></div><div class="message"><button type="button" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" class="close"><span aria-hidden="true" class="mdi mdi-close"></span></button><strong>Hata!</strong> Geçerli bir e-posta ve telefon numarası giriniz.</div></div>');
          }
          }
      });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Ajax and normal requests are different. HTML validation required will not work with ajax

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: whats really your question? do you get an error?

Comment: What @SagarV? That is the first I've ever heard that.

Comment: havent error. on console

Comment: https://buoran.com/sifremi-unuttum.php   just click send understand my problem

Comment: @JayBlanchard he didn't mention how he submit. If it is by a simple button click or blur, the required attr won't take effect

Comment: He isn't submitting at all @SagarV, there is no code for the submission.

Comment: form submit is okay just problem validation required. fields empty form sending...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You may use [preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to prevent default functionality

```
$(function() {
$('form').submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var data = $('input[name="telefon"]').val();
if(data.length > 0)
{
  function uyem() 
}
else
{
  alert('Input are not valid');
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell your form if it needs to be submitted or not.

```
<form onSubmit="uyem()"></form>

function uyem() {
    $.ajax({});

    return false;
}
```

---

Returning `false` means do not submit form, while `true` means do submit.

Comment: Or, since the user is already using jQuery, they could capture the click event without having any inline JS. :)

Comment: @JayBlanchard I guess OP has `<input type="submit" onClick="uyem()">`, so basically it's the same. But since OP does not provide this info - I do not fix anything with that.

Comment: Yeah - it's hard to know without details.